# React Native disabling going back on Slider

Tags: reactjs, react-native, slider

Hello everyone in my React Native app I am using a slider and that slider has 100% width. On slider there is a dot and the user can move it horizontally but when the dot is too close to left side of the screen and user tries to swipe it to right navigation starts and screen goes back. I've added some props to the component and it works on iOS but not on Android. Here is the code:

````
          <Slider
            value={numberOfColumns}
            onValueChange={value => {
              if (value === 3) value += 1;
              pageContext?.setState({ numberOfColumns: value });
            }}
            maximumValue={3}
            minimumValue={1}
            step={1}
            allowTouchTrack
            trackStyle={{ height: 1.5, backgroundColor: '#292929' }}
            thumbStyle={{
              height: 18,
              width: 18,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#292929',
              backgroundColor: '#292929'
            }}
            onStartShouldSetResponder={() => false}
            onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture={() => true}
            onResponderTerminateRequest={() => true}
            onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() =>
              navigation.setOptions({ gestureEnabled: false })
            }
            onResponderGrant={() => {
              navigation.setOptions({ gestureEnabled: true });
            }}
          />
```
and here is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHnRE.png
````

Comment: which package are you using for `Slider`

Comment: Actually my slider is a custom component that uses Pan Responder and Animated

Comment: Why you are not using available packages for Slider like `SliderBox` etc.